# How to extract pol & zero data from amplifier's data sheet?

Tags: amplifier, frequency, gain, model

I am looking at the OPA548 amplifier's data sheet and trying to extract the corner frequencies but i am unable to accurately do it, as i can only make assumptions based on the open loop gain/phase graph, so what should i do ?

[Link to datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa548.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Smells of a misunderstanding or an XY problem. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am trying to create a spice model of the amplifier, implementing each pole as low pass filter.

Comment: OK understood but why does the graph not give you what you want?

Comment: i meant that any values off the graph are estimates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the DS states that the minimum open-loop gain is 90 dB and is typically 98 dB. From this you could estimate that the mximum might be 106 dB. This of course reduces to typically 90 dB with an 8 ohm load.

But it's all a little superficial because a model can never predict the full extent of what might happen across 1,000+ devices. You have to be pragmatic and try and model with typical values  - that's how models are made and it is down to the skill of the design engineer using those models to figure out which parameters are critical to his design and tweak them to see if desired circuit performance is compromised. That is also what Monte Carlo analysis does.

Comment: another question i have what should the gain value of the vcvs in my model be ??! i think it is gonna be V/V value since it is dB and not dBm but what i am not sure about is it dB20 or dB10 ?

Comment: If this is the DC gain then it's going to by typically 98 dB or 79,433. 100 dB is 100,000; 80 dB is 10,000; 60 dB is 1,000 etc..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not home right now, but here's a basic, ideal way to make it in LTspice, as a subcircuit:

```
.subckt ideal_opa548 IN- IN+ OUT params: Aol=106 Gbw=850k Rout=50
G1 0 out IN+ IN- {10**(Aol/20)/Rout}
C1 out 0 {10**(Aol/20)/(2*pi*Gbw*Rout)} Rpar={Rout}
.ends ideal_opa548
```

I didn't check the datasheet for `Rout`, and only ogled the gain-bandwidth, so add your own. Here's how it would look like in the schematic editor:

[image: opa548]

The response is with an 8\$\Omega\$ (load) and 8G\$\Omega\$ (no load). In `.AC` it looks fine, but in `.TRAN` you'll encounter problems with output swing (not limited). For this you can start the long way to complication by adding an appropiate "totem-pole" with `SW`, which will draw current, then an appropiate driver, input resistance/impedance, voltage limiting, ...